# how do you interpret this diagram?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

there is poll to evaluate the number of women that are working. The number of women is 784. And we have the following variables:

X: Is one if the woman was working in 2008.

Y: is the average age of the children. And is 0 if the woman doesn't have kids. We have 3 groups $Y=0, 0<Y<3, Y>3$

What is the correct answer?

a)If the average age of of the kid increases then the woman works more.

b) There is no correlation between the average age and the participation of the woman in the labor force

c)  When the average age is between 0 and 3, the participation of the woman in the labor force is lower.

Blue: working

White: not working

[image]

Apparently the correct answer is b, but i dont know why. Maybe is wrong?

Comment: It seems you are translating from another language; are you sure that you have translated the text correctly into English? For example, "relation" is not a statistical term, did you mean correlation? If you try to improve your written English, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, correlation is the correct word. Is already edited. im sorry, if you find more mistakes please let me know :).

Comment: It seems that you have one binary variable (X) and a ratio variable (Y) grouped onto an ordinal scale coded as 0, 0<Y<3, and 3<Y. The standard Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient _r_ is not possible on such low level data, therefore the answer is b.